# Blender python exporting hidden objects gives no mesh, and unhiding them in a script only sort of works

Tags: python, export

I'm writing an export script with bpy, and I had an issue where when I exported hidden objects (through the script) the fbx exported looked like it had no mesh. I then tried unhiding in the editor and rerunning the script, and then the fbx file was correct and showed the object as expected. I tried unhiding the objects I was exporting through the Object.hide_set(False) method, but this still gave no mesh (so maybe it was waiting to unhide until after the script ran??). Then, since all of the objects were unhidden in the editor (after the previous run was completed), I tried to run the script again, and this time the meshes were correct. Does anyone know what's up with this?

TL;DR
Meshes only export as expected (or at least, as I would expect) if already unhidden in the editor. Unhiding through script doesn't help immediately.

Comment: Are your fbx files that have the hidden files the same size as the ones with them visible? Maybe a better approach would be to place the hidden meshes in a new `Collection` or just an array for export?